# Cannot send empty message - Discord.JS v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Error: `DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message`
Code:

```
if(message.content == 'a!up')
    {
        const AllowedupMessage = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(process.env.AllowedAuthor)
        .setDescription(process.env.AllowedDescription)
        .setFooter(process.env.VNetworkFooter)
        .setColor(process.env.AllowedColor);
        message.channel.send({ embeds: [AllowedupMessage] })
    }
```

I can't figure out how to fix this stupid error.  Thanks on your help :) <3

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the version you have of Discord.js

But judging from your code, I guess it's v13

[Discord.js Guide Updating from v12 to v13](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#sending-messages-embeds-files-etc)

Example Sending messages, embeds, files, etc. Updating from v12 to v13
The footer has been changed, now use:

```
.setFooter({text: 'Someone text', iconURL: 'link'})
```

The same for `.setAuthor`

```
- channel.send(embed);
+ channel.send({ embeds: [embed, embed2] });

- channel.send('Hello!', { embed });
+ channel.send({ content: 'Hello!', embeds: [embed, embed2] });

- interaction.reply('Hello!', { ephemeral: true });
+ interaction.reply({ content: 'Hello!', ephemeral: true });
```